# Is there any way to save the trained data in Verilog?

Tags: database, verilog

I wish to train a robot about the indoor environment with multiple obstacles. To save the trained data by this, is there anyway in verilog..!! This training data should be used by robot while deploying with dynamic data to move from one point to another in the trained indoor environment. What will be the best way of implementation in Verilog..!!

Comment: why verilog? Are you developing a machine learning hardware? The problem you describe are mostly related to software. Use a generic programming language instead. BTW, in verilog you can read/write files but this is as much as you can get. No concept of database exits there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog is a Hardware Design Language. Thus you should think it terms of 'hardware'. There does not exist something like a "hardware database".

The nearest and simplest I can think off, would be to make an SD-card interface and write raw data sectors to the SD-card.

You will then need a special program to extract the data as computers like to see a FAT32-data structure.

<sub>By the way: the option to read or write files only exists in a simulation environment. I don't know any synthesis tool which supports file I/O.</sub>